# Swift Admob Interstitial Adv. status bar

Tags: ios, swift, admob, adsense, firebase-admob

I implement the google interstitial adv. in my app and it is working correctly. But it is not hide status bar and it say in console:

Status bar could not be hidden for full screen ad. Ensure that your app is configured to allow full screen ads to control the status bar. For example, consider whether you need to set the childViewControllerForStatusBarHidden property on your ad's rootViewController.

I could not find any way to fix it. How can I fix it and hide the status bar. Because sometimes close icon is under status bar and it is not working.

My code:

```
func showInterstitial(){
        
        let interstitalId = Advertisement.sharedInstance.interstitialAddUnit
        
        let request = GADRequest()
        GADInterstitialAd.load(
            withAdUnitID: interstitalId, request: request
        ) { (ad, error) in
            if let error = error {
                debugPrint("Failed to load interstitial ad with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            self.interstitial = ad
            self.interstitial?.fullScreenContentDelegate = self
            
            if let ads = self.interstitial {
                
                ads.present(fromRootViewController: self)
            } else {
                debugPrint("Ad wasn't ready")
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to set `prefersStatusBarHidden` value as true inside your view view controller

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
}
```

Comment: tried it and not working :(